# How does Blizzard determine if I preordered a retail copy of Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

Procrastination caused me to only reserve my copy of Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls this morning at Best Buy. I'm not sure this will count as a preorder by which I can earn preorder loot. How does Blizzard determine what constitutes a Diablo 3: Reaper of Souls preorder?

Comment: The most logical guess would be some form of one-time-use code in addition to the serial key, given out by retailers or inside the packaging for the game.

Comment: @TZHX agreed, just trying to figure out if this mornings reservation will count based on how they're doing it. Hoping someone who went through the process will have the answer.

Comment: If you are talking about these golden wings that everybody has now, then the answer would be: "They don't. You just have to register your copy **before 31/03** to get these wings". Otherwise I don't have any idea how they track it. Most probably just like @TZHX said

Comment: Hey Ash, if you feel like any of the answers below helped you out, go ahead and mark it with a check!

Comment: @Mkalafut thank you for the reminder, I had forgotten to close the loop on this question. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you redeem your CD key / activation key before March 31st, you will get the pre-order bonuses.  A member of my online community bought the game digitally yesterday and got the wings without pre-ordering.

Technically if you went to your local retailer and bought a copy before March 31st you'll still get your pre-order bonuses.

TL;DR: Anyone who redeems their activation (retail or digital) key before the end of March will get their pre-order bonuses.

Additionally, if you pre-ordered a physical copy of the game but didn't receive it before March 31st, [you can receive the pre-order items by submitting a ticket to Blizzard support](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-reaper-of-souls-loot).

Answer (score 2):

In Germany we don't have Best Buy but I preorder my games at Gamestop. There you get an piece of paper with an one-time-use code inside the game's box or they hand it out when you come to get your game at the release date.

I think Best Buy would do it in the same way. I'm pretty sure the game will include an one-time-use code.

Comment: Now that the game is available for retail and preorders from third party sites have been honoured, has anyone actually received such a code? I pre-ordered a copy from GMG and got no such code apart from the registration key for the game that was in the box with the disc.

Comment: It's possible that the registration key includes data about your preorder but it's just a guess.

Comment: @Kurley, refer to my answer.  All codes redeemed before March 31st will get the pre-order items.

Comment: @Mkalafut I've upvoted your answer ;-)

Comment: @Kurley Thanks!  Hopefully he selects an answer at some point.